# Anyone know of free / OSS nfs server for Windows?

Tags: windows, nfs

I am in need of an Windows NFS server for a VMware script I am working on. I have tried Windows SFU and WinNFSd and both did not do so well, WinNFSd did not connect to VMware at all and Windows SFU is not very good.

It would be a great deal of help to me if someone know of something, I am possibly thinking of moving my script work and such over to Linux if the pickings are really that slim.

The problem I had with Windows SFU was simply performance it flat out was horrible and kept loosing connection with ESXi. WinNFSd just flat out would not connect seeing as it cannot host NFS over TCP which is what ESXi wants.

Comment: You'd get better answers if you told us what you didn't like about those two products you already tried...

Comment: Agree with ErikA - SFU is a fairly mature product and I've used NFS sharing from Windows to a VMWare Environment before.

Comment: Did you verify that it was actually SFU that was causing the problems? NFS can fail in a lot of ways, and I'd point to network and/or firewall issues before placing blame on SFU. That said, if you truly want bulletproof NFS, stick with linux or one of the BSDs.

Comment: Yeah I checked that there was no firewall causing issues this was internal network only and I usually disable client firewalls on my "testing" equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a built-in NFS server service from Server 2003 R2 onward. This is completely separate from SFU and can be installed from Windows Components (2003 R2) or Add Roles (2008 through 2012 R2 inclusive).